Trust alert immediately disappears when connecting iPad to Mac
When connecting an iOS device to a Mac, an alert will pop up on macOS asking whether to trust the external device.
This alert, however, only appears for the blink of an eye, for some reason, and then suddenly disappears.
I have no chance to hit "Allow".
See here for a GIF: trust-alert.gif
Does anyone know how to fix this weird bug? (Running macOS 14.4.1) ‍‍♂️

Well, I was able to work around this issue by repeatedly hitting the return key on my keyboard as fast as I can while, at the same time, connecting my iPad.
Not a good solution though.
